# Macro to generate a method that will iterate over every field

Tags: c++, macros

For a given struct e.g.

```
struct Foo {
 int a;
 std::string b;
};
std::string to_string(const Foo&);
```

I want to generate a body of to_string function.
Is it possible to implement it with such interface? e.g.:

```
GENERATE_TO_STRING(Foo,a,b)
```

Assuming that every member has defined << operator for streams, or to_string function - doesn't really matter.

I'm asking specifically for a macro, because I can't make changes in the header file. So this is specific kind of "reflection".

Comment: why are you asking specifically for a macro?

Comment: Well I'm just guessing that it will require a macro, and I can't make edits in header file, only in source file

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/GvEYsc8ce